# php page blank when echoing multiple divs

Tags: php

Every time I try and echo multiple divs using php the page loads completely blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content">
  <div class="w3-container">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span><center><form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
<textarea name='title'></textarea>
    <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
<textarea name='description'></textarea>        
<textarea name='message'></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Post!</button>
</form></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work

```
echo '<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content">
<div class="w3-container">
<span onclick="document.getElementById(\'id01\').style.display=\'none\'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span><center><form method=\'POST\' action=\''.setComments($conn).'\'>
<textarea name=\'title\'></textarea>
<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'uid\' value=\''. $_SESSION['username'] . '\'>
<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'date\' value=\'' .date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). '\'>
<textarea name=\'description\'></textarea>        
<textarea name=\'message\'></textarea><br> <button type=\'submit\' name=\'commentSubmit\'>Post!</button>
</form></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
```

But you should revise this code. Its too complicated thus error prone.

Comment: I think you want to recheck your quotes too.

Comment: @deg: yup! you are correct. Checked. Code should not look like this!

Answer (score 3):

Check your quotes.

You are echoing between single quotes `'`. Every time you add an unescaped (`\`) single quote, you break the string you are echoing.

Either use `"` (`name="title"` etc.) or escape the `'`s (`getElementById(\'id01\'`).

This bit for example, remembering your original quotes are single:

```
<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
```

should be

```
<form method="POST" action="'.setComments($conn).'">
```

The page being blank is ultimately the result of a server error, due to malformed  php, due in your case to the broken up echo instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are all messed up.

```js
function id01displaynone() {
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';
}
```

```html
echo '<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content">
  <div class="w3-container">
    <span onclick="id01displaynone();" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span><center><form method="POST" action="'.setComments($conn).'">
<textarea name="title"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="'.$_SESSION['username'].'">
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value="'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'">
<textarea name="description"></textarea>        
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="commentSubmit">Post!</button>
</form></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
```

I used a function instead of putting it directly inside of the onclick, and changed your ' with " inside the echo.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to echo all the different lines?:
Also has another answer check the quotes i noticed that too!

> Either use " (name="title" etc.) or escape the 's (getElementById(\'id01\').
>   This bit for example, remembering your original quotes are single:
>
> ```
> <form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
> ```
>
> should be
>
> ```
> <form method="POST" action="'.setComments($conn).'">
> ```

```
<?php
echo "<div id=\"id01\" class=\"w3-modal\">\n"; 
echo "<div class=\"w3-modal-content\">\n"; 
echo "  <div class=\"w3-container\">\n"; 
echo "    <span onclick=\"document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'\" class=\"w3-button w3-display-topright\">&times;</span><center><form method='POST' action='\".setComments($conn).\"'>\n"; 
echo "<textarea name='title'></textarea>\n"; 
echo "    <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='\".$_SESSION['username'].\"'>\n"; 
echo "    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='\".date('Y-m-d  H:i:s').\"'>\n"; 
echo "<textarea name='description'></textarea>        \n"; 
echo "<textarea name='message'></textarea>\n"; 
echo "    <br>\n"; 
echo "    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Post!</button>\n"; 
echo "</form></center>\n"; 
echo "</div>\n"; 
echo "</div>\n"; 
echo "</div>\n"; 
echo "</div>\n";
?>
```

Comment: i have tried to echo all the different lines however this did not work